# Find all unsorted pairs in partially sorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have to find (or atleast count) all pairs of (not necessarily adjacent) unsorted elements in a partially sorted array.

If we assume the sorting to be ascending, the array `[1 4 3 2 5]` has the following unsorted pairs: `(4, 3)`, `(3, 2)` and `(4, 2)`.

I'm thinking of an algorithm that works along the lines of insertion sort, as insertion sort tends to compare every new element with all elements which are misplaced with respect to the new element.

Edit: While posting the question, I didn't realise that finding the pairs would have a higher time complexity than counting them. Is there a better possible algorithm that just counts how many such pairs exist?

Comment: This can be done in O(nlogn), think of a binary search tree.

Comment: @SomeDude If the input is (almost) sorted in descending order, you have O(n^2) pairs to report.

Comment: @Thomas I m thinking of inserting them in a binary search tree, whenever you insert on a left child, update the number of "left" insertions at each node while traversing. You will get the result. In an input of decreasing order of the array, all the insertions will be on left side.

Comment: @SomeDude But since you have to create a return value containing O(n^2) entries, your algorithm cannot run in O(nlogn).

Comment: I was thinking of "count" rather than listing, then it makes sense.

Comment: @SomeDude Is it possible to count them in a better than O(n^2) complexity?

Comment: @FitzWatson SomeDude already laid out the algorithm for counting in O(nlogn) time using a binary search tree.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a little bit on what you mean exactly by "partially sorted" - One could argue that *every array* is partially sorted to some degree.

Since this algorithm has worst-case complexity `O(n^2)` anyway (consider the input sorted in *descending* order), you might as well go down the straight-forward route:

```py
ret = []

for i in range(len(array)):
    for j in range(i, len(array)):
        if array[i] > array[j]:
            ret.append((array[i], array[j]))

return ret
```

This works very well for random arrays.

However, I suppose what you have in mind is more something that there are larger stretches inside the array where the numbers are sorted but that that's not the case for the array as a whole.

In that case, you can save a bit of time over the naive approach above by first identifying those stretches - this can be done in a linear pass. Once you have them, you only have to compare these stretches with each other, and you can use binary search for that (since the stretches are in sort order).

Here's a Python implementation of what I have in mind:

```py
# find all sorted stretches
stretches = []
begin = 0
for i in range(1, len(array)):
    if array[i-1] > array[i]:
        stretches.append(array[begin:i])
        begin = i
if i+1 > begin:
    stretches.append(array[begin:])

# compare stretches
ret = []
for i in range(len(stretches)):
    stretchi = stretches[i]
    stretchi_rev = None
    
    for j in range(i+1, len(stretches)):
        stretchj = stretches[j]

        if stretchi[-1] > stretchj[0]:
            if stretchi_rev is None:
                stretchi_rev = list(reversed(stretchi))

            hi = len(stretchj)
            for x in stretchi_rev:
                i = bisect.bisect_left(stretchj, x, 0, hi)
                if i == 0:
                    break
                else:
                    for y in stretchj[:i]:
                        ret.append((x, y))
                    hi = i
        
return ret
```

For random arrays, this will be slower than the first approach. But if the array is big, and the amount of partially sorted portions is high enough, this algorithm will at some point starting to beat the brute-force search.

Comment: However, both algorithms have a asymptotic complexity of O(n^2), right?

Comment: In the worst case, yes, you cannot get faster than that.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @SomeDude in the comments, if you just need to count pairs there's an `O(nlogn)` solution based on building a binary search tree. There are some subtleties involved - we need to keep track of the number of duplicates (`ic`) at each node, and for performance reasons we also keep track of the number of right children (`rc`).

The basic scheme for inserting a value `v` intro the tree rooted at node `n` is:

```
def insert(n, v)
  if v < n.data
    count = 1 + n.ic + n.rc
    if n.left is null
      n.left = node(v)
      return count
    return count + insert(n.left, v)
  else if v > n.data
    if n.right is null
      n.right = node(v)
      n.rc = 1
      return 0
    n.rc += 1
    return insert(n.right, v)
  else // v == n.data
    n.ic += 1
    return n.rc
```

And here's some functioning Java code ([Ideone](https://ideone.com/FTX9uO)):

```
static int pairsCount(Integer[] arr) {
    int count = 0;
    Node root = new Node(arr[0]);
    for(int i=1; i<arr.length; i++)
        count += insert(root, arr[i]);
    return count;
}

static int insert(Node n, int v) {
    if(v < n.value) {
        int count = 1 + n.rc + n.ic;
        if(n.left == null) {
            n.left = new Node(v);
            return count;
        }
        return count + insert(n.left, v);
    } 
    else if(v > n.value) {
        if(n.right == null) {
            n.right = new Node(v);
            n.rc = 1;
            return 0;
        }
        n.rc += 1;
        return insert(n.right, v);
    }
    else {
        n.ic += 1;
        return n.rc;
    }
}

static class Node {
    int value;
    Node left, right;
    int rc; // right children count
    int ic; // duplicate count
    
    Node(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
Integer[] arr = {1, 4, 3, 2, 5};
System.out.println(pairsCount(arr));
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: Except that this does not implement a binary search tree at all. Since you're not balancing your tree, this will result in linear insertion time (and hence an overall complexity of `O(n^2)` again) in the worst case.

Comment: @Thomas I have to disagree - it is a binary search tree, just not a balanced one. As such you're correct that worse case runtime will be `O(n^2)`, but average will be `O(nlogn)`. The question asks about partially sorted arrays, so I believe the latter is more applicable.

Comment: You're right, the expected runtime is `O(nlogn)` for random inputs. But our inputs are not random, we know that they're partially sorted. And the more sorted the input is, the more your implementation will behave like a linear list.